# Understanding why a binary operator is associative. ( On a property of "fractional part of a sum" operation)

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

Define the binary operation which gives the fractional part of a real number $x$ like so:

$$x +_1 y = \{x + y\}$$

where

$$\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$$

Now we want to show that this operator is associative on the interval $[0, 1)$.

The proof I found in my book is like this:

> We make use of the fact that $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an integer:
>   \begin{align*}
> x +_1 y &= \{x + y\} \\
>         &= x + y - \lfloor x + y \rfloor
> \end{align*}
>
> So $x +_1 y$ is equal to $x + y$ minus some integer.
>
> Then for $x, y, z \in  [0, 1)$:
>   \begin{align*}
> (x +_1 y) +_1 z &= (x + y - p) +_1 z \\
>                 &= (x + y - p) + z - q \\
>                 &= (x + y + z) - (p + q)
> \end{align*}
>
> And:
>   \begin{align*}
> x +_1 (y +_1 z) &= x +_1 (y + z - r) \\
>                 &= x + (y + z - r) - s \\
>                 &= (x + y + z) - (r + s)
> \end{align*}
>
> Where $p, q, r, s \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> **Since $(x +_1 y) +_1 z$ and $x +_1 (y +_1 z)$ both lie in the same interval,
>   the integers $(p + q)$ and $(r + s)$ must be equal** and hence the following holds:
>
> \begin{equation*}
> (x +_1 y) +_1 z = x +_1 (y +_1 z)
> \end{equation*}

I don't quite follow the bolded deduction.

- They say that both "$(x +_1 y) +_1 z$ and $x +_1 (y +_1 z)$ lie in the same interval", ok, that makes sense, because of the definition of the $+_1$ operator.
- But why does this imply that $(p + q)$ and $(r + s)$ must be equal?

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for operators like $\operatorname{frac}$ using `\operatorname{frac}$`.

Comment: @Max. Made an edit in order the title allows a easier  research in the question bank. But I am not sure whether it it relevant.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: I meant the question " bank"

Comment: As to your question, can you take advantage of the fact that x+y+z lies in  [0, 3) ? and then derive other inequalities from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $(x +_1 y) +_1 z = (x+y+z) - (p+q)$ and that $x +_1 (y +_1 z) = (x+y+z) - (r+s)$. If we take the floor of both of these expressions both of the left hand sides will be equal to zero so we get.

$$0 = \left \lfloor (x+y+z) - (p+q) \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor (x+y+z) - (r+s) \right \rfloor$$

Because $p+q$ and $r+s$ are integers, they can be taken out of the floor function to give
$$0 = \left \lfloor x+y+z \right \rfloor - (p+q) = \left \lfloor x+y+z \right \rfloor - (r+s).$$

Ignoring the zero at the start and just focusing on the second part of the equality we can subtract $\left \lfloor x+y+z \right \rfloor$. This gives us

$$ -(p+q) = -(r+s) $$

from which the result easily follows.